# How to auto autocomplete in google-colab, that is avoid hitting tab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

How to use hinterland or auto autocomplete in google colab?
How to avoid hitting tab again and again?
I setup hinterland but it does not work.

Does google-colab have this feature?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SpaceBar</kbd> is what worked for me on Firefox

Comment: It works for me on Chrome as well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Google colab comes with tab-completion:

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/basic_features_overview.ipynb#scrollTo=d4L9TOP9QSHn

You only have to hit tab once to get a list of all options available.

[image]